# JQuery Mobile ajax form throws 301 error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, post

I have a website with a directory called mobile. I am using jQuery mobile.
My login form uses my own ajax call as such:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function() {
$("#form_login_mobile").on("submit", function(e) {   
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("/ajax_requests/auth.ajax.php", { form: $("#form_login_mobile").serialize(), method: "login"  }, function(data) {    
                if(data.success) {
                   alert("SUCCESS!");
                } else {
                    alert("FAILED");
                }
            }, "json");
     });
});
```

Firebug throws the error `mysite.com/ajax_requests/ajax.php 301 Moved Permanently`
I have other ajax calls not using jQuery Mobile that work fine. I tried adding `data-ajax="false"` to my form but still the same error. I'm sure its the jQuery Mobile causing
the issue but I have no idea where or how. What could be the problem?

Comment: 301 is not an error. It's information from the server telling you that the resource you asked for is somewhere else. Check the URL you are using, and make sure that it is what you think it is. You can get it from Firebug's Net tab.

Comment: Doh! It was https and I forgot to force it on the mobile pages! All set.